# Remove the border of the programmatically created Custom Button

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I know to set the border to the button by the following ways,

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.5;
button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
```

But I need to know how to remove or delete the border of the button?

Comment: work around try changing the border alpha value as to it will become transparent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
```

Will make the border invisible.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.6 blue:0.9 alpha:0.1];
//                                set 'alpha' to something less than 1. -----^^^
```

Try this !

Answer (score 0):

On a UILabel this doesn't work, I used the following (considering you added only 1 Sublayer)
(This is in Mono C# but you can translate it pretty easily)

```
label.Layer.Sublayers[0].RemoveFromSuperLayer();
```